# Does changing activities affect threads?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

**Sorry in advance for pseudo code, I'm short on time at the time of writing this**

I'm curious if activity switching\finishing effects running threads?

For example:

In MainActivity

```
ClassContainingWhileLoop ccwl = new ClassContainingWhileLoop();
Thread myThread = new Thread(ccwl);
myThread.start();
```

In ClassContainingWhileLoop

```
ClassContainingWhileLoop extends Runnable

run()
{
WhileLoopClass();
}

WhileLoopClass
{
while(true)
{
...stuff to do in thread...
}
}
```

I have try/catch blocks set up, but the problem is more that everything works as I need it until I switch activities, so no errors. I have confirmed that the thread does, in fact, stop running once someone returns to the original activity.

I'm familiar with how the lifecycle of android apps work, but I'm not sure if threads are affected by the change if they are never "touched" again (I have a boolean check keeping it from being rerun if navigating back to the original activity to avoid continuously starting new threads.)

The use I'm going for: I open serversocket and sockets for quick connections (send one message and close sockets), but I need to keep the serversocket open until the app is destroyed.

I'm aware that Services are the "best" way to go here, but I just can't seem to figure them out. I've tried several times, read through the docs on them multiple times, and looked up a million examples of them. Maybe I can figure them out in the future, but at the moment I'm wondering if there is an alternative way to keep threads running for the life of an app without using services.

Comment: Your thread will continue to run until A.) the Runnable returns, or B.) the OS preemptively terminates your app (process death) because it has determined your task is no longer important enough, e.g., user has switched to another app, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the activity lifecycle methods take place in a single thread called main thread or UI thread. When you run a new thread like `new Thread(new Runnable....).start()`, the activity starts a separate thread independent of main thread. So your activity lifecycles doesn't affect a thread. Moreover thread has its own lifecycle methods.

Comment: Lifecycle basically are the stages a computer program undergoes, from initial creation to deployment and execution. For more information regrading java thread you can check here [link](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/multi-threading/java-thread-life-cycle-and-thread-states/)

Answer (score -1):

one way is using `fragments`.you can use fragments for it and call  `setRetainInstance(true)` in fragment .that cause when you navigate between `activities` and `fragmnets` android keep your thread.

Comment: @greeble31 yes but it cause android keep variables of fragments on navigationing and replacing  .and thread stay as a variable of fragment

Comment: The question is about the lifetime of the thread, not the availability of the thread reference (which the OP appears to be declaring it as a local variable).